# apt-get fails with "There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes"

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, postgresql-9.4

When installing postgres 9.4 on ubuntu 14.04 using postgres, I get the following error

```
There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Here's my task:

```
---
- name: Add postgres repository
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main' state=present

- name: ensure apt cache is up to date
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: ensure packages are installed
  apt: name={{item}}
  with_items:
    - postgresql-9.4
```

How is this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the repository keys. After you add the repo, add this step:

```
- name: Add postgres repo key
  apt_key: url=https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc state=present
```